Estimates for the logarithmic derivative of $\Lambda(s,\chi)$
We have the following estimate about the logarithmic derivative of $\xi_0(s)=s(1-s)\dfrac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta_\infty(s)}$ for $s=\sigma+it$ and $\rho=\beta+i\gamma$:
$$
\frac{\xi_0'}{\xi_0}(s)=\sum_{\rho\in Z(\xi_0)}\frac{1}{s-\rho}+O(1)=\sum_{\rho\in Z(\xi_0),|\rho\pm t|\leq 1}\frac{1}{s-\rho}+O(\log(|t|+2))
$$
Meanwhile, the only estimate I know about $\Lambda(s,\chi)=\dfrac{L(s,\chi)}{L_\infty(s,\chi)}$ is:
$$
\text{Re}(\frac{\Lambda'}{\Lambda}(s,\chi))=\sum_{\rho\in Z_\chi(\Lambda)}\text{Re}(\frac{1}{s-\rho})
$$
with no information about the imaginary part. Is there any estimate on the imaginary part of $\dfrac{\Lambda'}{\Lambda}(s,\chi)$, and on its modulus in general?
($Z(\xi_0)$ and $Z_\chi(\Lambda)$ denotes the nontrivial zeroes of $\zeta(s)$ and $L(s,\chi)$ respectively.)

what is $\zeta_\infty(s)$? - this being said what prevents you from using the proof in Titchmarsh for the $\zeta$ and modifying it to $\chi$ at least for a primitive such where you have a similar functional equation; you will get an $O$ depending on the modulus of $\chi$ and the dependence there may be trickier, but for an individual $\chi$ or for a fixed modulus where you do not care about that dependence the result should be same
